# Required Programming Languages to write a own application in ubuntu?

Tags: application-development

What are the minimum requirements to write an ubuntu app?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting - you should go with Python - http://python.org

You should check this: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/programming-languages/python/

You have also nice introduction to the tools here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Programming

You have information how to start here:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

Comment: i have basic knowledge with python....

Comment: Just added you link 'get started' - it contains nice introduction - I think what you are after for

Comment: but i don't familiar with graphics programming....... i know c and java very well and i know shell scripting also..... can i make an app with shell scripting alone?

Comment: Yes, you can make an app with shell scripting alone - I don't know what what can of app you want to make - you will be more limited than using Python. What really you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to contact with you.... can i have your email address?

Comment: bluszcz[hereisat@]bluszcz.net ?